# What is the value of X without using logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following is from the UK textbook [CGP A-Level Maths 2017-2018](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/178294723X). Exercise 3.1 Q6 part a.

The question asks that you find the value of x in the following equation.

$$4^x = \sqrt[3]{16}$$

I can solve this by using logarithms but as they are later in the book and as this question is in the section on the 'Law of Indices' I think the intention is to rearrange the equation.

However, I cannot quite get there.

Comment: Presumably, you are meant to know that $\sqrt[3]{a} = a^{1/3}$, and to observe that $16 = 4^2$.  Then $4^x = (4^2)^{1/3} = 4^{2/3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $3\sqrt{16}$ actually means $\sqrt[3]{16}$, it is simple:\begin{align}4^x=\sqrt[3]{16}&\iff4^x=(4^2)^{1/3}\\&\iff4^x=4^{2/3}\\&\iff x=\frac23.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can write:
$$
\sqrt[3]{16}=\sqrt[3]{4^2}=\left(4^2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=4^{2\cdot\frac{1}{3}}=4^{\frac{2}{3}},
$$
so $x=\dfrac{2}{3}$ as in the accepted answer.